# How do you access dictionary values when keys are stored in another object?

Tags: python

Say I have two objects like this:

```
d={'a':{'z':1,'y':2},'b':{'z':0,'y':4}}
k=('a','y')
```

How can I use these two objects to get:

```
>>> d['a']['y'] 
2
```

I need it to be dynamic so this won't work:

```
d[k[0]][k[1]]
```

because I am not always sure of the dictionary's nesting depth. `k` could have one element or several.

Comment: I think we might need a little more context to answer this one.  What does the actual data look like, and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: @JeffL. I disagree, I think the problem is pretty clearly stated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
try:                  
    # python 3 maybe?
    from functools import reduce                  

except ImportError:
    # assume python 2...
    pass                  

reduce(dict.__getitem__, k, d)
```

A bit of explanation was requested: reduce(fn, [a1, a2, a3...], b) translates into: fn(... fn(fn(fn(b, a1), a2), a3) ...). So, it pairs some "accumulator" value with consecutive values from the sequence, passes that to the function passed in and then uses that to update the "accumulator" value.

So our "accumulator" value is top-level dictionary, which we pass as the first ("self") argument into dictionary method `__getitem__`, which implements subscript operator.

As noted in the comments below you can use `operator.getitem` in place `dict.__getitem__` to generalize to other datatypes that support indexing such as lists, tuples, strings...

Comment: What if I'm in python3?

Comment: `reduce` has been buried in `functools` in python 3.

Comment: Consider adding that to the answer, since this question isn't tagged either way. Also, I upvoted because this is correct, but consider providing a teensy bit of explanation about what's going on here, as the one line is not too instructive to anyone not familiar with python's functional tools

Comment: Beautiful solution, though I would rather use `lambda dic, key: dic[key]` for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Do you have any suggests for how you might increment that object? Say to get something like d['a']['y']+=1?

Comment: @EliKorvigo: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.  I find `lambda dic, key: dic[key]` to be ugly.

Comment: What about `operator.getitem`?

Comment: Actually, @EliKorvigo suggestion is not purely aesthetic, but generalizes the solution to other nested structures that are not dictionaries but support subscripting, e.g.: lists. I'll update solution accordingly.

Comment: @LMc:  To increment the value in the innermost dict do `*k, last_k = k`.  And then do `reduce(dict.__getitem__, k, d)[last_k] += 1`.  This will work at any level of nesting.  Given `d = {'a':{'b':{'c':1}}, 'd':1}` it will work where `k = ('a', 'b', 'c')` and where`k = ('d',)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think Adam's solution is by far the cleaner one, but because there's always an imperative alternative to the functional approach, we could also solve this recursively:

```
 def get(d,k):
     if len(k) == 1:
             return d[k[0]]
     return get(d[k[0]], k[1:])
```

Similarly with for loops:

```
result = d.copy()
for key in k:
    result = result[key]
```

Noting that loops don't have their own scope in python